Compiling select files in subdirectory and placing in obj folder using make
I am trying to compile certain files from a subdirectory for unit testing. I want to compile ./under_test/test_code.cpp and place the object file into ./obj folder.
Right now I can compile the files in working directory and place in obj and build and link that way. I can not figure out how to get the files from the subdirectory compiled. Please any help with with awesome.
TARGET_EXEC ?= unit_test

IDIR =./include
CC = g++ --std=c++14
CFLAGS = -g $(INC) -I$(IDIR)

BUILD_DIR = obj
SRC_DIRS ?= .


INC = -Iunder_test
LIBS = -lgtest -lgmock

# DEPS = $(wildcard $(IDIR)/*.h)

# SRCS := $(shell find . -name '*.cpp')
SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)

TEST_SRCS = under_test/test_code.cpp

# _OBJ = main.o state.o
OBJ = $(SRCS:%.cpp=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

all: $(TARGET_EXEC)

$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJ)
    @echo linking $^
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(TEST_SRCS)
    @echo compiling $^
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@


.PHONY: clean
.PHONY: show

SOURCES := $(shell basename -a under_test/test_code.cpp \
                                under_test/more_test_code.cpp)


show:
    echo $(SOURCES)

clean:
    rm -f $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~ 
    rm $(TARGET_EXEC)

This is what I have but i am getting
compiling main.cpp  under_test/test_code.cpp
with:
g++ --std=c++14 -g  -I./include -c main.cpp under_test/test_code.cpp -o obj/main.o

The error:
g++: fatal error: cannot specify ‘-o’ with ‘-c’, ‘-S’ or ‘-E’ with multiple files


This is wrong in a few ways:
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(TEST_SRCS)
         @echo compiling $^
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

The $^ automatic variable expands to ALL the prerequisites.  But in make every recipe should explain how to build one single target, not multiple targets.  So this recipe should be for compiling ONE source file, not ALL the source files.  This is why you're seeing that compiler error, because you're calling one instance of the compiler with multiple source files.  You want to use $< which expands to just the first prerequisite.
That's leads to the second problem: you don't want to list ALL the source files as prerequisites here, because that means whenever you change ONE source file you're saying that ALL object files have to be rebuilt.
You want just:
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
         @echo compiling $<
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

You don't really say what you want to do with the test object files.  If you want them to be linked into TARGET_EXEC you can just add the sources to SRCS.
If you want them to be compiled but not linked anywhere, you can add the object files to all:
TEST_SRCS = under_test/test_code.cpp
TEST_OBJS = $(TEST_SRCS:%.cpp=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

all: $(TARGET_EXEC) $(TEST_OBJS)

